# Alias-like structure in Java

Tags: java

I have simplified my problem. For example, in the following code snippet, carsList is empty at the beginning and listEmpty is naturally true. However, after the first line, I have added new item to the list and printed results. The value of listEmpty Boolean has not changed when carsList.isEmpty returned as expected false.

```
Boolean listEmpty = carsList.isEmpty(); //carsList.isEmpty() returns true

carsLists.add(car1);

System.out.println("ListEmpty: " + listEmpty + " CarsList.isEmpty:" + carsList.isEmpty); // ListEmpty: true CarsList.isEmpty: false
```

I need an alias-like structure which always points the latest result of a method.

```
alias = carsList.isEmpty(); //carsList.isEmpty() returns true

carsLists.add(car1);

System.out.println("Alias: " + alias + " CarsList.isEmpty:" + carsList.isEmpty); // Alias: false CarsList.isEmpty: false
```

When the result of a method changes, the value of the alias-like structure should change accordingly.

### Edit

The selected solution is not what i was looking for but it was the closest. The other solutions were also perfect and can be used in other cases.

Comment: Just call the method every time? There is no auto-updating magic variable

Comment: use a fucntion instead of the alias directly, duh.. `private Boolean isAlliasEmpty()`

Comment: Sometimes, in order to access the list, four or five other methods should be called. The readibility of the code suffers.

Comment: There are many possible ways to achieve what you're looking for. But I don't see any requirement to do this. Every possible implementation will add overhead to your code performance. Not only this, but it will also be more errorprone as extra coding will be added. For example, what if you forget to refresh your `boolean` at some place where your list is updated. `isEmpty()` of `List` Collection is already simplified to be used directly as many times as you want. + it also guarantees it will never return a wrong value. I would suggest use `isEmpty()` method only whenever required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With Java 8 you can use the `Function` interface:

```
carsList.add(car1);
Function<List<?>, Boolean> empty = List::isEmpty;

System.out.println("ListEmpty: " + empty.apply(carsList) + " CarsList.isEmpty:" + carsList.isEmpty());
```

Comment: I was suggesting a similar answer, but you might need to save a reference to your `carsList` inside a lambda or something, if it doensn't change that might make it easier

Comment: @xander I would be happy to see your solution as well.

Comment: My fault, I changed the answer to `apply`. It is from `java.util.function.Function`.

Comment: could also use `Supplier<Boolean> empty = carsList::isEmpty` which reduces the call to `empty.get()`, i.e. no need to supply the list. But I fail to see how that's better than `carsList.isEmpty()`.

Comment: @zapl My problem was not with carsList.isEmpty(). When i need to call several methods to access whether the list is empty or not, i thought there is certainly a better way to do it. For example, i use your username as alias and zapl means superLong().function().nesting().getList().isEmpty(). Whenever i type zapl, i want to get the result of other call.

Answer (score 2):

Call the method every time. `isEmpty()` usually is super fast,
<sup>more precisely O(1).</sup>

If you need to call a lot of functions to access the list in the first place, "alias" the list instead:

```
List<> myList = superLong().function().nesting().getList();
myList.isEmpty();
myList.isEmpty();
...
```

instead of

```
superLong().function().nesting().getList().isEmpty();
superLong().function().nesting().getList().isEmpty();
...
```

Answer (score 1):

```
private Boolean isListEmpty(){
   return carsList.isEmpty()
}
```

Instead of accessing the boolean variable, use this method to check for the boolean condition like

```
System.out.println("Alias: " + isListEmpty() + " CarsList.isEmpty:" + carsList.isEmpty);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a lambda returning a Supplier instance. It will work the same as passing by reference the latest result of method invocation:

```
// note the final keyword
final List<...> list = ...
Supplier<Boolean> isEmpty = () -> list.isEmpty();
// now you can return it and use somewhere else
return isEmpty; 
...
list.add(...);
...
System.out.println("Is list empty? " + isEmpty.get());
```

Comment: This is also very good solution (+1). In my case, one of the variable (aEvent) is not final and it gives the following error *Local variable aEvent defined in an enclosing scope must be final or effectively final*

Comment: @BernhardColby the only variable required to be final for this solution is the object for which you are querying the state. You can either make it final or assign the value to another final variable (but here you must understand how this decision will impact your code).

Comment: Yes, in my current code is not good for your solution but normally, I will certainly need it.

Answer (score 0):

Then you probably want to use the Observer pattern. Her is how you use it: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/observer_pattern.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the Reactive extensions for Java which intrinsically uses the observer pattern:

https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxJava

In the example above you can implement these as follow:

```
Observable oCarList = Observable.fromIterable(carList);
oCarList.subscribe(
  new Consumer<Car>() {
      @Override
      void accept(Car car) {
        //Method that executes when a car is added
        System.out.println(car.toString());
      }
  }
)
```